# bootstrap 5 slider interval not working properly

Tags: slider, bootstrap-5

**bootstrap 5 slider:** I am manually setup   `interval: 1000` millisecond ,
but first slide take more than `1000` millisecond &  then other slide iterate okay .. & **end of the every iteration** first slide delay more than `1000` millisecond .

**How do I fix that ?**
would someone help me to figure it .. thanks in advance

**Code Below**

```js
var myCarousel = document.querySelector('#carouselExampleDark')
var carousel = new bootstrap.Carousel(myCarousel, {
  interval: 1000,
  
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div id="carouselExampleDark" class="carousel carousel-dark slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-inner" style="height: 300px;">
    <div class="carousel-item active" data-bs-interval="10000">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption  d-md-block">
        <h5>First slide label</h5>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="2000">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?grayscale" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption  d-md-block">
        <h5>Second slide label</h5>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?blur" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption  d-md-block">
        <h5>Third slide label</h5>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Your first and second slides have the `data-bs-interval` attribute, with the first slide set to 10 seconds and the second set to 2 seconds. Try removing those as they seem to be overriding the interval you’re trying to set using JavaScript.

Comment: @Rich DeBourke thank for the help... if you want .. post as an answer .. I gladly accept .. thanks again..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code for BS5's Carousel has it that if element has a `data-bs-interval` then that value is used, otherwise it uses the default.  Default is `5000` but if you instantiate it with a value (like you do with `interval: 1000`) then that value is used.

You can add either:

- add `data-bs-interval="1000"` to each *carousel-item* CSS, and remove the instantiator from the JS, or
- remove the `data-bs-interval=` from your existing CSS code and keep the `interval: 1000` in the JS

For interest - the code in [`carousel.js`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/js/src/carousel.js)  that does the setting  (extracted form Github):

```js
 _updateInterval() {
    const element = this._activeElement || SelectorEngine.findOne(SELECTOR_ACTIVE_ITEM, this._element)

    if (!element) {
      return
    }

    const elementInterval = Number.parseInt(element.getAttribute('data-bs-interval'), 10)

    if (elementInterval) {
      this._config.defaultInterval = this._config.defaultInterval || this._config.interval
      this._config.interval = elementInterval
    } else {
      this._config.interval = this._config.defaultInterval || this._config.interval
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use the `data-bs-interval` attribute, like this

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="10000">
```

Here I set the interval to 10 seconds, so it's 2 times longer than the default bootstrap 5 interval, which is 5 seconds

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
For me it's working fine when I place the data-interval="xxx" directly to the main div. See example:

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" data-interval=1000 class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not work because you have written 10000(ten-thousand intervals) just write this   {   data-bs-interval="1000"  }.
MIstake -write 1000 intervals intead of 10000.